# Using asymptotics to show a sequence is increasing

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics, power-series

I want to show that for a particular series I have of the form $\sum_{n=0}^N a_n x^n$ it is true that for the coefficients $a_{n+1} > a_n$ in the range.

I'd like to check the validity of two separate lines of argument:

1. If I can show $a_n \sim f(n)$ as $n\to \infty$ and that $f'(n) >0$ is it enough to give me $a_{n+1} > a_n$?
2. Suppose we can express $a_n = b_n/c_n$. If $b_n \sim \beta(n) $ and $c_n \sim \gamma(n)$ as $n\to \infty$ and $\beta(n) > \gamma(n)$ is it enough to imply $a_{n+1} > a_n$?

If not, is there some argument with asymptotics I could use? The reason I want to use this route is the form of $a_n$ is not nice to work with but its asymptotic expansion is nicer.

Comment: 1. counterexample: $a_{2n}=2n$, $a_{2n+1}=2n$, $f(x)=x$. Btw, your original expression is a polynomial since you sum up to a finite $N$.

Comment: @Gary a polynomial in $x$, yes. My goal is to show it has no root at $x=1$, that is, that the sum is non-zero always. And I know from checking lots of values the coefficients are strictly increasing, so I want to show that someway. I was hoping asymptotics was an option.

Comment: Can you give us the specific polynomial?

Answer (score 1):

Both of the statements are incorrect. Here are counterexamples :

1. Consider $f : x \mapsto \sin(2 \pi x)$. For every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, one has $f'(n)=2 \pi \cos(2 \pi n) = 2 \pi > 0$, but $a_n = \sin(2 \pi n) = 0$ for every $n$, so $a_{n+1} = a_n$ for every $n$.
2. Let $b_n = c_n = n$. Then one has $b_n \sim n+1$ and $c_n \sim n$, and obviously $n+1 > n$, but for every $n$, one has $$a_n =\frac{b_n}{c_n} = 1$$

so the sequence $(a_n)$ is not strictly increasing.